# control over individual particles in a CCParticleSystemQuad?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I am calling setTexture:withRect: on a particle emitter...  My question is, is there any way I can give multiple rects so that the particles can be comprised of random sprites?  Or is the only way to accomplish this to use multiple emitters?

I thought if there was a way to actually get the collection of particles that are being generated, then I could loop over them and set their rect, or even color properties, but in the cocos2d docs, I see no way to get individual particle objects......  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want emitted particles to have different images, you can make sprite sheet of your particle images and subclass CCParticleSystemQuad overriding `initTexCoordsWithRect:` method so that instead of using same frame for very particle it uses different frames for different particles.

See [here](http://indieambitions.com/code-snippits/cocos2d-particle-engine-wdifferent-sprites/) for example of such particle system using bitmap font. Using the same idea, I made CCParticleSystemQuad subclass which uses CCSpriteFrameCache to get frame information.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access or modify individual particles.

If you want random sprites, simply run multiple particle systems with each using a different texture.